# How to simplify following boolean expression? A+A'BC+BC'?

Tags: boolean-algebra

please help I'm stuck. 
I'm trying to solve this.

[image]

so far I have: 
a) a+b+c 
b) a+bc 
c) a+b 
d) a+b

but for e) I can't progress further since I don't know how to deal with a'bc in this case. 
anyone so kind to please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a + \overline abc = a + bc$$ since we have $a$ or $\overline a bc$. If not $a$, then $\overline a$. That must follow if not a. So "it goes without saying", that if not $a$, (then we already know $\overline a$) so it suffices to assert $bc$.

A similar argument can be made for $bc + \overline bc$, but perhaps simpler, in this case, we can use the distributive property:
$$bc + \overline b c = (b +\overline b)c = 1c = c$$

Combining the simplifications gives us  $$a+\bar a b c+\bar b c=a+c$$

Comment: that makes sense finally! may I ask if you can see if the correct answer for f) is ab+a'c?

Comment: I argue with my classmate. he says the answer for f) is ab+c?

Comment: The correct answer is $ab + c$. I just double checked, and arrived at $ab+ c$.

Comment: I made it until ab+(a'b')*c. how do you get rid of the a'b' please?

Comment: $ab + a'c + b'c = ab + (a'+b')c$. Now, if $ab$ is false, then $\lnot (ab) = a' + b'$ is true, meaning either $a'$ is true, or b' is true. In either case,  $a' + b'$ is true. So either $ab$ is true, or if false, then we already know $a'+b'$ must be true, in which case it suffices to declare that $(a'+b')c$ is true provided $c$ is true. If $ab$ is false, the truth value of $(a'+b')c$ depends only on $c$.

Comment: omg now that makes sense....thank you so much. for g) it's a+c'?

Comment: It should be $a + b' +c'$

Answer (score 0):

$a+\bar a b c= a+bc$ and $bc+\bar b c=c$, so $a+\bar a b c+\bar b c=a+c$

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer.
but I can't quite follow how you get from a+a'bc=a+bc.
a+a'= 1
if you pull A out it would be for me a(1+bc)?